# Display times from different object in the same day React native

Tags: react-native

My idea is that i want to display a bunch of days with hours in front of them from data i'm fetching,example:
Monday: 08:00 to 13:00
friday: 14:00 to 17:00 13:00 to 19:00
the data i fetch looks like this:

[image]

so its an array of objects where jour= day and heure1:hour1.so i did map it in my code like this:

```
 {
                        (this.props.data.lieux[0].horaires) ?
                        this.props.data.lieux[0].horaires.map((lng, ney) => {
                            return <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                              <View >
                                <Text>{lng.jour}</Text>
                              </View>
                              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#bdc3c7', margin: 5 }}>
                                <Text  style={{ margin: 5 }}>{lng.heure1}</Text>
                                <Text  style={{ margin: 5 }}>{lng.heure2}</Text>
                              </View>
                            </View>
              
                          })
                          :
                          <></>
                      }
```

but the problem is i want if the objects have the same day (jour=day= monday) i should put the hours on the same view. not 2 different view with the same day.
i hope i make it clear enough and i really would appreciate your help!
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash _.groupBy method to join the data on the same day. I've created an example using reactJS here: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-night-mb053?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

[image]

Please have a look.

Comment: thank you for reply, but i'm new to react native and i never worked on Reactjs, i struggled to implement your solution